# Some confusion in Doppler effect in accelerated motion

Tags: reference-frames, acceleration, doppler-effect

I am sharing two solved questions based on Doppler effect in Accelerated motion .Although I have understood the methods for both the questions , I wanted to know what is the difference between the two questions since they have completely different methods although the questions looks similar to me . Why cant both be solved from same methods?

Basically my doubt is that in
question 1 : where we used time difference between two successive pulses to reach observer
question 2 : where approach is similar to some straight line motion question (but why here we did not consider time between two successive pulse etc like that of above question)

NOTE: I have studied or basically learnt just the formula for Doppler Effect (with all bodies in uniform motion) without studying its derivation. Is it due to this that I am unable to understand the difference between the above two questions / difference between approach between the two types of problems?
Also please explain the the last line of question 1

[image: question 1 : where we used time difference between two pulses to reach observer]

[image: question 2 : where approach is similar to some straight line motion question (but why here we did not consider time between pulse etc like that of above question)]

Answer (score 0):

They term 2cf is very large in problem 2 compared to the value of a . Hence this approach works for accurate results use approach 1.